# Print something to console after x milliseconds

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so, after lets say, 1 minute so 60000 milliseconds the console will say hi.

All I have so far is

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
timer.Start();
```

But I don't know how to make it so when the timer is done, it will do something.

Comment: Subscribe to the `Elapsed` event.  See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example.

Comment: if all else fails read the manual

Comment: The Timer class has a TimerElapsed event. Subscribe to it and implement any functionality that you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the elapse event, when 60000 ms has pass the event will be thrown. Example of the elapse event:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(elapse); // subscribing to the elapse event
        timer.Start(); // start Timer
        Console.ReadLine(); // hold compiler until key pressed

    }

    private static void elapse(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hy");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
void Main()
{
var t = new System.Threading.Timer((s)=>Console.WriteLine("Hi"),null,0,60000);
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` if you only want to do the write once (the timer will run every x seconds):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
Console.WriteLine("something");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is create an event that writes to the console when the timer has elapsed the predefined amount of time.

**This is done as follows:**

Start by creating your timer and set it to 60s:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000); //60seconds
```

Next create an event that will be triggered when the time has elapsed:

```
private static void MyEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Next, bind the timer to that event:

```
timer.Elapsed += MyEvent;
```

What this does is tell the computer that when the timer actually starts running in the future and then the timer elapses (60s passes after the timer starts), then the Event called 'MyEvent' will be called which writes to the console.

**Finally** Start the timer:

```
timer.Start();
```

And wait for the even to trigger and write to the console.